# Could kd-tree build with dot-product?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

A normal kd-tree is constructed by recursively split the super plane into half. And to do range search with a query point, it will only search a small bunch of points(log) in stead of all(linear).

I wonder a kd-tree can be built with dot product?

For example, b is a list of 3d vector:

```
b = np.random.rand(10,3)

a = (1,1,1) is a query vector
```

and I want to find nearest bk which satisfy:

```
a * bk > a * bi, for i = 1, 2, ...k-1, k+1, 10
```

I do not want to calculate all a * bi dot product pairs.

How can I build a tree with b, and when query a come, I only calculate some of a * bi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Ram & Gray 2008](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.6101.pdf) is exactly what you're looking for. They call their structure a "cone tree".